# Operation ongoing in step (1) Match Files/Via MatchAll/Match filepatterns for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state process

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow pipeline that reads a lot of files (at least 5 million documents) and attempts to store it in a database.

I have the following pipeline execution:

```java
StorageToXrOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
      .withValidation()
      .as(StorageToXOptions.class);
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<KV<String, String>> docs = p
    .apply("(1) Match Files", FileIO.match().filepattern(options.getInputFile()))
    // withCompression can be omitted - by default compression is detected from the filename.
    .apply("(2) Read Matches", FileIO.readMatches())
    .apply("(3) Transform into KV", MapElements // uses imports from TypeDescriptors
        .into(kvs(strings(), strings()))
        .via((FileIO.ReadableFile f) -> {
            try {
                return KV.of(
                    f.getMetadata().resourceId().toString(), f.readFullyAsUTF8String());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read the file", ex);
            }
         }));
```

`options.getInputFile()` returns a wildcard selection on a subset of the GCS objects. This pipeline has worked with fewer number of files in the past, but with the current size (5-6 million documents), FileIO.match() times out.

I receive the following error logs:

```
Operation ongoing in step (1) Match Files/Via MatchAll/Match filepatterns for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state process
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:476)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:470)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1354)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:963)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:754)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
  at app//com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
  at app//com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:149)
  at app//com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
  at app//com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
  at app//com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541)
  at app//com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474)
  at app//com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)
  at app//com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation$AbstractGoogleClientRequestExecutor.call(ResilientOperation.java:171)
  at app//com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry(ResilientOperation.java:67)
  at app//com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry(ResilientOperation.java:106)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.listObjects(GcsUtil.java:346)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.listObjects(GcsUtil.java:324)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.expand(GcsFileSystem.java:222)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.lambda$matchGlobs$0(GcsFileSystem.java:195)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem$$Lambda$234/0x0000000800516c40.apply(Unknown Source)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.transform(Iterators.java:785)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:273)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:234)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList(FluentIterable.java:617)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.matchGlobs(GcsFileSystem.java:200)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.match(GcsFileSystem.java:101)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:124)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:145)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:157)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$MatchAll$MatchFn.process(FileIO.java:660)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$MatchAll$MatchFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
"
```

```
Operation ongoing in step (1) Match Files/Via MatchAll/Match filepatterns for at least 10m00s without outputting or completing in state process
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.lang.String.intern(Native Method)
  at app//com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.getFieldInfo(ClassInfo.java:126)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:441)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:787)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:641)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:744)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:451)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:787)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:360)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:335)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:79)
  at app//com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:73)
  at app//com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:451)
  at app//com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)
  at app//com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation$AbstractGoogleClientRequestExecutor.call(ResilientOperation.java:171)
  at app//com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry(ResilientOperation.java:67)
  at app//com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry(ResilientOperation.java:106)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.listObjects(GcsUtil.java:346)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.listObjects(GcsUtil.java:324)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.expand(GcsFileSystem.java:222)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.lambda$matchGlobs$0(GcsFileSystem.java:195)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem$$Lambda$234/0x0000000800516c40.apply(Unknown Source)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.transform(Iterators.java:785)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:273)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:234)
  at app//org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList(FluentIterable.java:617)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.matchGlobs(GcsFileSystem.java:200)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.match(GcsFileSystem.java:101)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:124)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:145)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:157)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$MatchAll$MatchFn.process(FileIO.java:660)
  at app//org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$MatchAll$MatchFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
```

and two other timeout exceptions, e.g.:

```
Operation ongoing in step (1) Match Files/Via MatchAll/Match filepatterns for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state process
  at java.base@11.0.9/sun.security.provider.SHA.implCompress(SHA.java:129)
```

and

```
Operation ongoing in step (1) Match Files/Via MatchAll/Match filepatterns for at least 10m00s without outputting or completing in state process
  at java.base@11.0.9/java.util.Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:1607)
```

Am I using a wrong API to read from GCS? I would assume Apache Beam + Cloud Dataflow would easily be able to read 5/6 million documents. Owing to these errors, my pipeline execution halts and the job does not complete.

Please advise on what could be possible solutions to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, reading this many files should not be a problem for Dataflow, but matching them all in one synchronous operation could have issues (as demonstrated).

A possible workaround is to break your single pattern into a number of smaller patterns and use [FileIO.matchAll()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#matchAll--), e.g.

```
PCollection<KV<String, String>> docs = p
    .apply("(0) Input Patterns", Create.of("/path/to/a*", "/path/to/b*", ...))
    .apply("(1) Match Files", FileIO.matchAll()
    ...
```

Comment: Hi @robertwb. Thank you for your suggestion. In some instances I would like to read the entire bucket at once. Are there any options similar to TextIO.withHintMatchesManyFile for any optimisation for this?

Comment: You can read the entire bucket, assuming the set of patterns has full coverage of the entire bucket (e.g. "/path/to/[char]*" for char in 0...255). I'm not sure what you mean by "at once" as the files themselves are read on a distributed set of machines.