# Building Splittable DoFn (SDF) to list objects in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to develop custom source for parallel GCS content scanning. The naive approach would be to loop through listObjects function calls:

```
while (...) {
    Objects objects = gcsUtil.listObjects(bucket, prefix, pageToken);
    pageToken = objects.getNextPageToken();
    ...
}
```

The problem is performance for the tens of millions objects.
Instead of the single thread code we can add delimiter **/** and submit parallel processed for each prefix found:

```
...
Objects objects = gcsUtil.listObjects(bucket, prefix, pageToken, "/");
for (String subPrefix : object.getPrefixes()) {
    scanAsync(bucket, subPrefix);
}
...
```

Next idea was to try to wrap this logic in Splittable DoFn.

Choice of **RestrictionTracker**: I don't see how can be used any of exiting **RestrictionTracker**. So decided to write own. **Restriction** itself is basically list of prefixes to scan. **tryClaim** checks if there is more prefixes left and receive newly scanned to append them to current restriction. **trySplit** splits list of prefixes.

The problem that I faced that **trySplit** can be called before all subPrefixes are found. In this case current restriction may receive more work to do after it was splitted. And it seems that **trySplit** is being called until it returns a not null value for a given **RestrictionTracker**: after certain number of elements goes to the output or after 1 second via scheduler or when **ProcessContext.resume()** returned. This doesn't work in my case as new prefixes can be found at any time. And I can't checkpoint via **return ProcessContext.resume()** because if split was already done, possible work that left in current restriction will cause **checkDone()** function to fail.

Another problem that I suspect that I couldn't achieve parallel execution in **DirectRunner**. As **trySplit** was always called with **fractionOfRemainder=0** and new **RestrictionTracker** was started only after current one completed its piece of work.

It would be also great to read more detailed explanation about Splittable DoFn components lifecycle. How parallel execution per element is achieved. And how and when state of RestrictionTracker can be modified.

UPD: Adding simplified code that should show intended implementation

```
@DoFn.BoundedPerElement
private static class ScannerDoFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
    private transient GcsUtil gcsUtil;

    @GetInitialRestriction
    public ScannerRestriction getInitialRestriction(@Element String bucket) {
        return ScannerRestriction.init(bucket);
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public ProcessContinuation processElement(
            ProcessContext c,
            @Element String bucket,
            RestrictionTracker<ScannerRestriction, ScannerPosition> tracker,
            OutputReceiver<String> outputReceiver) {
        if (gcsUtil == null) {
            gcsUtil = c.getPipelineOptions().as(GcsOptions.class).getGcsUtil();
        }
        ScannerRestriction currentRestriction = tracker.currentRestriction();
        ScannerPosition position = new ScannerPosition();
        while (true) {
            if (tracker.tryClaim(position)) {
                if (position.completedCurrent) {
                    // position.clear();
                    // ideally I would to get checkpoint here before starting new work
                    return ProcessContinuation.resume();
                }
                try {
                    Objects objects = gcsUtil.listObjects(
                            currentRestriction.bucket,
                            position.currentPrefix,
                            position.currentPageToken,
                            "/");
                    if (objects.getItems() != null) {
                        for (StorageObject o : objects.getItems()) {
                            outputReceiver.output(o.getName());
                        }
                    }
                    if (objects.getPrefixes() != null) {
                        position.newPrefixes.addAll(objects.getPrefixes());
                    }
                    position.currentPageToken = objects.getNextPageToken();
                    if (position.currentPageToken == null) {
                        position.completedCurrent = true;
                    }
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    logger.error("Error during scan", throwable);
                }
            } else {
                return ProcessContinuation.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    @NewTracker
    public RestrictionTracker<ScannerRestriction, ScannerPosition> restrictionTracker(@Restriction ScannerRestriction restriction) {
        return new ScannerRestrictionTracker(restriction);
    }

    @GetRestrictionCoder
    public Coder<ScannerRestriction> getRestrictionCoder() {
        return ScannerRestriction.getCoder();
    }
}

public static class ScannerPosition {
    private String currentPrefix;
    private String currentPageToken;
    private final List<String> newPrefixes;
    private boolean completedCurrent;
    public ScannerPosition() {
        this.currentPrefix = null;
        this.currentPageToken = null;
        this.newPrefixes = Lists.newArrayList();
        this.completedCurrent = false;
    }
    public void clear() {
        this.currentPageToken = null;
        this.currentPrefix = null;
        this.completedCurrent = false;
    }
}

private static class ScannerRestriction {
    private final String bucket;
    private final LinkedList<String> prefixes;
    private ScannerRestriction(String bucket) {
        this.bucket = bucket;
        this.prefixes = Lists.newLinkedList();
    }

    public static ScannerRestriction init(String bucket) {
        ScannerRestriction res = new ScannerRestriction(bucket);
        res.prefixes.add("");
        return res;
    }

    public ScannerRestriction empty() {
        return new ScannerRestriction(bucket);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return prefixes.isEmpty();
    }

    public static Coder<ScannerRestriction> getCoder() {
        return ScannerRestrictionCoder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class ScannerRestrictionCoder extends AtomicCoder<ScannerRestriction> {
        private static final ScannerRestrictionCoder INSTANCE = new ScannerRestrictionCoder();
        private final static Coder<List<String>> listCoder = ListCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of());

        @Override
        public void encode(ScannerRestriction value, OutputStream outStream) throws IOException {
            NullableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()).encode(value.bucket, outStream);
            listCoder.encode(value.prefixes, outStream);
        }

        @Override
        public ScannerRestriction decode(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
            String bucket = NullableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()).decode(inStream);
            List<String> prefixes = listCoder.decode(inStream);
            ScannerRestriction res = new ScannerRestriction(bucket);
            res.prefixes.addAll(prefixes);
            return res;
        }
    }
}

private static class ScannerRestrictionTracker extends RestrictionTracker<ScannerRestriction, ScannerPosition> {
    private ScannerRestriction restriction;
    private ScannerPosition lastPosition = null;
    ScannerRestrictionTracker(ScannerRestriction restriction) {
        this.restriction = restriction;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryClaim(ScannerPosition position) {
        restriction.prefixes.addAll(position.newPrefixes);
        position.newPrefixes.clear();

        if (position.completedCurrent) {
            // completed work for current prefix
            assert lastPosition != null && lastPosition.currentPrefix.equals(position.currentPrefix);
            lastPosition = null;
            return true; // return true but we would need to claim again if we need to get next prefix
        } else if (lastPosition != null && lastPosition.currentPrefix.equals(position.currentPrefix)) {
            // proceed work for current prefix
            lastPosition = position;
            return true;
        }
        // looking for next prefix
        assert position.currentPrefix == null;
        assert lastPosition == null;
        if (restriction.isEmpty()) {
            // no work to do
            return false;
        }
        position.currentPrefix = restriction.prefixes.poll();
        lastPosition = position;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ScannerRestriction currentRestriction() {
        return restriction;
    }

    @Override
    public SplitResult<ScannerRestriction> trySplit(double fractionOfRemainder) {
        if (lastPosition == null && restriction.isEmpty()) {
            // no work at all
            return null;
        }

        if (lastPosition != null && restriction.isEmpty()) {
            // work at the moment only at currently scanned prefix
            return SplitResult.of(restriction, restriction.empty());
        }

        int size = restriction.prefixes.size();
        int newSize = new Double(Math.round(fractionOfRemainder * size)).intValue();

        if (newSize == 0) {
            ScannerRestriction residual = restriction;
            restriction = restriction.empty();
            return SplitResult.of(restriction, residual);
        }

        ScannerRestriction residual = restriction.empty();
        for (int i=newSize; i<=size; i++) {
            residual.prefixes.add(restriction.prefixes.removeLast());
        }
        return SplitResult.of(restriction, residual);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkDone() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (lastPosition  != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Called checkDone on not completed job");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IsBounded isBounded() {
        return IsBounded.UNBOUNDED;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `FileIO` or `TextIO` with wildcard :  `FileIO.match().filepattern("hdfs://path/to/*.gz")` ? In this case the GCS file content is retrieved in parallel.

Comment: Because it does it exactly ```MatchResult match = FileSystems.match(filepattern, emptyMatchTreatment);``` which in my case will return millions of files.

Possible solution explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713828/7374267. I am trying to generalize it by splitting matching logic. And to be able to have checkpointing when scanning directory with million of files.